# Perl: How to match FULLWIDTH LATIN SMALL

Tags: regex, perl, unicode, character-properties

I am using [listadmin](https://github.com/trentm/listadmin) to manage many mailman-based mailing lists. I have a long list of subjects and from addresses set up to block spam. Recently, I received smarter spam in the sense that it uses nice-looking Unicode characters, eg:

> Subject:  Ａl l ｔhe ad ult mov ies you' ve see n a r  e nothing c
>   ompari-
>             ng t o our eｘｘ xci t i ng compilation of 1３' ０00 mov ies in HD
>             t  hat arｅ a v ailable for y ｏu now!

or

> Subject:  HD qua lit y vi d eos an d pho to graph s ｏ f ho t c hic kｓ
>            are here for ｕ

Now I want to use a smart Perl regex to block that. Piping these subjects to hexdump revealed many characters are a [FULLWIDTH LATIN SMALL LETTER](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ff4f/index.htm). However, `\p{FULLWIDTH LATIN SMALL LETTER}` doesn't work: `Can't find Unicode property definition "FULLWIDTH LATIN SMALL LETTER"`

So the question is: Is there a `\p{something}` to match those fullwidth characters? Alternatively: is there another way to match those characters?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The page [`perlunicode`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlunicode.html#Unicode-Character-Properties) documents available unicode character classes. I found it as a reference in perlrebackslash, which documents special character classes and backslash sequences like `\p{...}` in regexes.

The summary is that all but the most common property classes require a property type and a property value, which are separated by `:` or `=`. However, there does not seem to be a mention of fullwidth characters as a predefined property.

But there is the `Block`/`Blk` property, which can have [`Halfwidth and Fullwidth Forms`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halfwidth_and_fullwidth_forms) (`U+FF00`–`U+FFEF`) as value:

```
/\p{Block=Halfwidth and Fullwidth Forms}/
```

This will match on your input (tested on v16.3).

---

A useful tool for this is [`uniprops`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Unicode%3a%3aTussle).

```
$ uniprops U+FF41
U+FF41 ‹ａ› \N{FULLWIDTH LATIN SMALL LETTER A}
    \w \pL \p{LC} \p{L_} \p{L&} \p{Ll}
    All Any Alnum Alpha Alphabetic Assigned InHalfwidthAndFullwidthForms
    Cased Cased_Letter LC Changes_When_Casemapped CWCM
    Changes_When_NFKC_Casefolded CWKCF Changes_When_Titlecased CWT
    Changes_When_Uppercased CWU Ll L Gr_Base Grapheme_Base Graph GrBase
    Halfwidth_And_Fullwidth_Forms Hex XDigit Hex_Digit ID_Continue IDC
    ID_Start IDS Letter L_ Latin Latn Lowercase_Letter Lower Lowercase
    Print Word XID_Continue XIDC XID_Start XIDS X_POSIX_Alnum
    X_POSIX_Alpha X_POSIX_Graph X_POSIX_Lower X_POSIX_Print X_POSIX_Word
    X_POSIX_XDigit
```

As you can see, `\p{Block=Halfwidth and Fullwidth Forms}` can also be written `\p{In Halfwidth and Fullwidth Forms}`.

Comment: many thanks @ikegami for the enlightening edit and the entertaining module it linked to.

Comment: It's one of tchrist's. `unichars` can be used to do the converse. e.g. `unichars -au '\p{InHalfwidthAndFullwidthForms}'` lists the chars in the HalfwidthAndFullwidthForms block.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `charnames::viacode` to get the character names from their codes:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use utf8;

use charnames qw();


my $string = q(Subject: Ａl l ｔhe ad ult mov ies you' ve see n a r e nothing )
            .q(c ompari- ng t o our eｘｘ xci t i ng compilation of 1３' ０00 )
            .q(mov ies in HD t hat arｅ a v ailable for y ｏu now!);

my $count = grep /FULLWIDTH/, map charnames::viacode(ord), split //, $string;
print "$count fullwidth characters.\n";
```